# Android: How to exclude ringtones and notifications from songs

Tags: android, mediastore

I am developing a music player application and querying for the album names through the following code :

```
Cursor mediacur = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
mediacur.moveToFirst();
do{
        albumindex = mediacur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        albumname = mediacur.getString(albumindex);
        songs.add(albumname);
  }while(mediacur.moveToNext());
```

I am getting all the album names along with Ringtones and Notifications too. How can I exclude the ringtones and notifications from my list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a selection to your managed query call.

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
Cursor mediacur = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);
```

Comment: Its working great. But how does Android System detects that particular music file is ringtone/notification? by seeing the folder name or it detects only preloaded music files or any other??